# Обход общих делителей

Tags: c#

Имеется ряд из 15 вопросов который подаются на экран по таким условиям:

```
if (i % 2 == 0){}
if (i % 3 == 0){}
if (i % 5 == 0){}
```

Как исключить накладку вопросов, а именно исключить выполнения условий при общих делителях например чисел 6,10,12,15.

Код по модификация else if:

```
if (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    { 

    }
    else if (j < dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1)
    {

    }
}
```

Фрагмент кода выдачи вопросов:

```
if(i==0 || i==1 || i % 2 == 0)
{
    if (f < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
    {
        // QuestionTime = DateTime.Now;
        textBox1.Visible = false;
        radioButton1.Visible = true;
        radioButton2.Visible = true;
        radioButton3.Visible = true;
        groupBox1.Visible = false;
        this.Text = Transfer;
        label1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[f].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        QuestionVariantString = dataGridView1.Rows[f].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        QuestionSplit = QuestionVariantString.Split(';');
        QuestionTrueChoice = dataGridView1.Rows[f].Cells[4].Value.ToString();

        radioButton1.Text = QuestionSplit[0];
        radioButton2.Text = QuestionSplit[1];
        radioButton3.Text = QuestionSplit[2];
        button1.Enabled = false;
        f++;
    }
}
else if (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0)
{
    if (j < dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1)
    {
        // QuestionTime = DateTime.Now;
        textBox1.Text = "";
        radioButton1.Visible = false;
        radioButton2.Visible = false;
        radioButton3.Visible = false;
        groupBox1.Visible = false;
        textBox1.Visible = true;
        label1.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        QuestionTrueChoice = dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        QuestionSense = textBox1.Text;
        j++;
    }
}
else if (i % 5 == 0 && i != 0)
{
    if (g < dataGridView3.Rows.Count - 1)
    {
        // QuestionTime = DateTime.Now;
        radioButton1.Visible = false;
        radioButton2.Visible = false;
        radioButton3.Visible = false;
        groupBox1.Visible = true;
        label1.Text = dataGridView3.Rows[g].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        QuestionVariantString = dataGridView3.Rows[g].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        QuestionSplit = QuestionVariantString.Split(';');
        QuestionTrueChoice = dataGridView3.Rows[g].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        checkBox1.Text = QuestionSplit[0];
        checkBox2.Text = QuestionSplit[1];
        checkBox3.Text = QuestionSplit[2];
        checkBox4.Text = QuestionSplit[3];
        g++;
    }
}
```

Когда I = 6 условия как я понял выполняются дважды и в следствии этого вопрос дублируется.

Comment: Использование else if вроде должно решить проблему. Или я не так понял вопрос...

Comment: Модифицировал но всё равно работает не так как нужно.

Comment: Делить на простые числа?

Comment: Да, ротация от 0 до 15. Вроде и расписал на бумаге и числа выписал общие но исключить никак не получается. Получается так что из 9 активных позиций 6 позиция проходится 2 раза. Следовательно зажёвывая 9 позицию.

Comment: @SAIBERPRO покажите код с модификацией под `else if`, скорее всего не так записали

Comment: if (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                { 
                    
                }
                else if (j < dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1)
                    {
                        
                    }
               
                
            }

Comment: @SAIBERPRO это лучше в вопрос дописать

Comment: О, FizzBuzz! Вам досталась классическая задача.

Comment: Обойти общие числа не получилось, до сих пор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что понял, что вам надо сделать. Но накидал базовый пример.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0 && i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} div on 2, 3, 5");
    }
    else if (i % 2 == 0 && i % 3 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} div on 2, 3");
    }
    else if (i % 2 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} div on 2, 5");
    }
    else if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} div on 3, 5");
    }
    else if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} div on 2");
    }
    else if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} div on 3");
    }
    else if (i % 5 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} div on 5");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} no any div");
    }
}
```

Comment: Хотел + добавить, но не могу ваша логи теоретически почти близка к тому что мне нужно а по моему даже оно, постараюсь аналогично переписать код и поверить вашу логику. Спасибо!